# Подскажите, пожалуйста, где нужны запятые

Tags: запятые

№ 1
Необходимо чтобы на счете была хотя бы одна копейка.
№ 2
К сожалению, это вся информация которую могу предоставить.

Answer (score 1):

### Необходимо, чтобы на счете была хотя бы одна копейка.

### К сожалению, это вся информация, которую могу предоставить.

В первом случае запятая ставится перед подчинительным союзом, во втором – перед союзным словом.

Если интересна тема, можете перейти по данной ссылке и всё прочесть: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=136#pp136 .